# Rvest returning empty paragraphs

Tags: r, rvest

While scraping text from a webpage using the rvest package, some paragraphs return empty but they should not.

The webpage is: 
https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000005620562

I want the paragraphs under the "articles", so I use ".article p" as CSS selector. It should return 9 paragraphs (5 should be empty as they are fillers). I do get 9 paragraphs, but 8 are empty!

```
page=read_html("https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000005620562")
html_text(html_nodes(page,".article p"))
```

I would post a screenshot but I don't have enough reputation...
Running this lines return a vector with 9 character strings but they are empty, exept the 8th one.
Paragraphs 1, 3 and 5 should contain text but here they appear empty.

Thank you all for your time.

EDIT:
A bit of context: I need to scrape a lot of pages from this website to get the core text of the articles to perform linguistic analysis on it.

The ".article p" CSS selector does a good job on most pages but the content of some paragraphs appear empty.

Comment: If you look at the source code for that page (what's actually returned from the http request), you'll see that the data really isn't inside `<p>` tags. They seem to have a bunch of odd closing `<p/>` tags. You can see the source with `cat(as.character(page))`. So the problem really is that your selector is incorrect. Note that if you are using Chrome, it may parse the page differently than `rvest` to be more forgiving of "bad" HTML.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know why it doesn't work. Is there a way to get the same parsing in R that in chrome?

Comment: You could use something like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/index.html) to run a headless version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do something like this?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rvest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     pluck
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     guess_encoding


page <- read_html("https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000005620562")

page %>% 
  html_nodes(".article") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_remove_all(pattern = "\nArticle\\s[0-9]")
#> [1] " En savoir plus sur cet article...\n\n   Sont désignées comme gares ferroviaires ouvertes au trafic international au sens de l'article 35 quater de l'ordonnance du 2 novembre 1945 susvisée au titre desquelles peuvent être créées des zones d'attente les gares suivantes :\n   Lille-Europe, Lille-Flandres, Aulnoye, Strasbourg, Thionville, Forbach, Metz, Sarreguemines, Pontarlier, Morteau, Modane, Cerbère, Nice, Hendaye, Calais-Fréthun, Paris-Gare du Nord, Paris-Gare de l'Est, Paris-Gare de Lyon.\n "
#> [2] " En savoir plus sur cet article...\n\n   Le présent arrêté abroge les dispositions de l'arrêté du 4 mai 1995 désignant les gares ferroviaires ouvertes au trafic international.\n\n "                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
#> [3] "\nLes préfets et, à Paris, le préfet de police sont chargés, chacun en ce qui le concerne, de l'exécution du présent arrêté, qui sera publié au Journal officiel de la République française.\n\n "
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer but your solution only works for this simple example.
I also work on pages like this one:
https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000029337646
I have to clean a lot more stuff

Comment: @RonDurand I just tested my code on that url, and I'm not quite sure what you mean when it only works for the first example. It went through and grabbed all paragraphs under the __article__. It might not result in the cleanest output, but that wasn't your original question.

Comment: The data I need to grab is the content of the paragraphs, between <p> and </p>. I don't want the "Article 1 En avoir plus sur cet article..." (fair enough we can clean this after).
On the second example I don't want the "Abroge Arrêté du 19 septembre..." (under article 1) or the "Modifié par Décret n°2016-1278 du 29 septembre 2016 - art. 1 (V) " (under article 3).
There is also the table in the end that I need to get rid of.

Comment: The original question is "why some paragraphs show empty when selected with the ".article p" selector?"